# Generating unique URLs for each date in the Codeigniter Calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a calendar controller and model that displays a monthly calendar. A user can click on the previous and next hyperlinks to iterate through the months. I have also been able to generate a unique URL for each day, so when someone wants to click on April 10, 2012 for example they will get a URL something like .../2012/04/10. My problem is that when I go to another month, all the date URLs still show April as the month.

Controller

```
function display($year = null, $month = null) {

    $this->load->model('CalendarModel');

    if ($day = $this->input->post('day')) 
    {
        $this->CalendarModel->add_calendar_data("$year-$month-$day", $this->input->post('data'));
    }

    $data['Calendar'] = $this->CalendarModel->generate($year, $month);

    $this->load->view('Calendar', $data);

}
```

Model

```
class CalendarModel extends CI_Model 
{

    var $conf;

    function CalendarModel() 
    {
        $date = (!isset($_GET['month']) && !isset($_GET['year'])) ? time() : strtotime($_GET['month'] . '/1/' . $_GET['year']); 

        $day = date('d', $date); 
        $month = date('m', $date); 
        $year = date('Y', $date);

        $this->conf = array(
            'start_day' => 'sunday',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'next_prev_url' => '/CodeIgniter/index.php/Calendar/display'
        );

        $this->conf['template'] = '
            {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">{/table_open}

            {heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}

            {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

            {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

            {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
            {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

            {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td class="day">{/cal_cell_start}

            {cal_cell_content}
                <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
                <div class="content">{content}</div>
            {/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}
                <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
                <div class="content">{content}</div>
            {/cal_cell_content_today}

            {cal_cell_no_content}<div class="day_num"><a href="/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/{day}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}<div class="day_num"><a href="/'.$year.'/'.$month.'/{day}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}

            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}

            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
        ';

    }

    function generate ($year, $month) 
    {

        $this->load->library('calendar', $this->conf);

        //$cal_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year, $month);

        return $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
  function CalendarModel($year = null, $month = null, $day = null)
  {       
         //$date = (!isset($_GET['month']) && !isset($_GET['year'])) ? time() : strtotime($_GET['month'] . '/1/' . $_GET['year']);
         //$day = date('d', $date);
         //$month = date('m', $date);
         // $year = date('Y', $date);  
         if ((is_null($year) || (is_null($month))
             {
                      // Do something if needed?
             }

          $this->conf = array( .... {continue rest of controller here as above}
```